# Не передает пакеты по событию OnTouch

Tags: android, клиент-сервер

Сделал программу, которая должна передавать по событию OnTouch координаты перемещения на сервер. Если я передаю координаты в таком же формате но через нажатие по кнопке то всё работает, а по OnTouch не хочет

Клиент:

```
TextView tv;
EditText et;
float new_x, old_x = 0;
float new_y, old_y = 0;
String sDown;
String sMove;
String sUp;

String serIpAddress;       // адрес сервера
int port = 10000;           // порт
String msg;                 // Сообщение
final byte codeMsg = 1;     // Оправить сообщение


/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    et = new EditText(this);
    et.setText("192.168.0.103");
    tv.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(et);
    setContentView(tv);

}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    new_x = event.getX();
    new_y = event.getY();

    EditText etIPaddress = et;
    serIpAddress = etIPaddress.getText().toString();
    if (serIpAddress.isEmpty()) {
        Toast msgToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Введите ip адрес", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        msgToast.show();
        return false;
    }

    SenderThread sender = new SenderThread();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
            sDown = "Down: " + new_x + "," + new_y;
            sMove = "";
            sUp = "";
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
            sMove = "Delta: " + (new_x - old_x) + "," + (new_y - old_y);
            old_x = new_x;
            old_y = new_y;
            sender.execute();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // отпускание
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            sMove = "";
            sUp = "Up: " + new_x + "," + new_y;
            break;
    }
    tv.setText(sDown + "\n" + sMove + "\n" + sUp);
    return true;
}

class SenderThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serIpAddress);
            Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);

            msg = "20|10";
            //msg = String.valueOf(old_x) + "|" + String.valueOf(old_y);
            byte[] outMsg = msg.getBytes("UTF8");
            out.write(codeMsg);
            out.write(outMsg);
            msg = "";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Сервер:

```
static int port = 10000;
    static IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0");
    const byte codeMsg = 1;     // Оправить сообщение
    const byte codeRotate = 2;  // Повернуть экран
    const byte codePoff = 3;    // Выключить компьютер
    const byte repOK = 10;
    const byte repERR = 20;
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {           
        // Создаем локальную конечную точку
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
        // Создаем сокет
        Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);            
        try
        {
            // Связываем сокет с конечной точкой
            socket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
            // Переходим в режим "прослуивания" соединения
            socket.Listen(1);                
            // Ждем соединение. При удачном соедиениее создается новый экземпляр socket, связанный с этим соединением
            while (true)
            {
                Socket handler = socket.Accept();
                // Массив, где сохраняем приняятые данные.
                byte[] recBytes = new byte[1024];
                int nBytes = handler.Receive(recBytes);                    
                switch (recBytes[0])    // Определяемся с командами клиента
                {
                    case codeMsg:                            
                        nBytes = handler.Receive(recBytes); // Читаем данные сообщения
                        if (nBytes != 0)                    
                        {
                            String msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recBytes, 0, nBytes);
                            String dx = msg.Split('|')[0];
                            String dy = msg.Split('|')[1];
                            SetCursorPos(Convert.ToInt32(dx),Convert.ToInt32(dy));
                        }                                
                        break;
                    case codeRotate:
                        RotateScreen();                           
                        break;
                    case codePoff:
                        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                        p.StartInfo.FileName = "shutdown.exe";
                        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-s -t 00";
                        p.Start();
                        socket.Close();                            
                        break;
                }
                // Освобождаем сокеты
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();
            }              


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
        }
```

Comment: Может потому что количество onTouch событий в секунду стремится к бесконечности?

Comment: А как часто тогда надо его передавать (каждый сотый, тысячный Touch) что бы оно заработало ?

Comment: Подбирать оптимально между возможностью и необходимостью, и лучше считать не по количеству а по времени, учитывая скорость соединения с сервером, иначе пока юзер водит пальцем запросы набиваются в очередь вплоть до OutOfMemory/StackOverflow

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Тогда я сейчас буду пытаться решить проблему со временем, после чего отпишусь

Comment: Попробовал добавить таймер - не передает данные. В итоге стал пробовать передавать данные разными способами (передавал константу) и как я понял он вообще не хочет их передавать и непонятно почему

Comment: Тогда пора учиться использовать дебаггер и логирование - без них отлов ошибок как гаданье на кофейной гуще.

Comment: setContentView() вызываете дважды -так неправильно.